# What is The Main Difference between PCA and NMF and why to choose one rather than the other?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I have to develop some analyses to study cancer data. I want to use NMF and PCA. Basically these tools choose the best factorization rank and the number of components that is meaningful to your analysis. Apart from this, is there anything more subtle that should push me to use one rather than the other? If so, could you please indicate some papers to cite along the paper to justify my possible choice?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://www.biostars.org/p/349136/ ?

Answer (score 11):

My informal, practical interpretation (which you should triple check) is that, given several features such as several genes, NMF gives you "metafeatures" (or "metagenes") that represent the main characteristics of the whole data. PCA gives you progressive approximations of the whole dataset.

The figure below comes from
page 555 of [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) (pdf is free). It shows that NMF splits a face into a number of features that one could interpret as "nose", "eyes" etc, that you can combine to recreate the original image. PCA instead gives you "generic" faces ordered by how well they capture the original one.

Whether you want one or the other depends on the purpose of the analysis, of course.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have got this book. I know that I don't know everything so I put down that question. The intent was to check whether the community could share something more profound with which refine a comment on a paper. But it appears that the usual issue "it depends from what you have to do" returns xD. Thank you anyway!